# How do you force a word to change case etc to preserve branding using jquery possibly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, branding

Let's say you are Apple... and sitewide you want every instance of iPod to always be proper case and structured to preserve the branding. I have a similar issue with a company that is not apple at all but has the same branding challenge.

So even if someone types IPOD or ipod or iPoD in the CMS running the site, it will appear correctly always as iPod

Even if there is a text-transform CSS on a headline making everything uppercase like IPOD ETC ETC, it will force the i lower case to be iPOD ETC ETC.

Even if there are plurals or variants like ipods, IPODAGE, iPoDdInG... and any bastardization of it will convert to the proper case - iPods, iPodage, iPodding

I've done some experimenting with the following script I found on jsfiddle and I'm not having much luck although I'm fairly unschooled with js in general.

http://jsfiddle.net/x9BSn/2/

I'm already pulling in jquery for a number of other things in the site so I am fine with utilizing it.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for this to be part of the editorial-function as the data goes INTO the CMS?

Comment: This is probably possible (not sure about that CSS case though, that one will be very hard), but I think such a global script is going to slow things down a lot. Much better to simply do this kind of thing any time you accept user input (i.e. before you store the input, as part of your sanitization), and then anything that isn't user-input is something you should be able to control and just have be correct in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modified `Shmiddty`'s solution a bit

```
$.fn.changeWord = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function () {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('(' + str+ '(?=(?:[^\>]|\<[^\<]*\>)*$))', 'gi'), "<span class='"+className+"'>$1</span>");
    });
};

$('#myDiv').changeWord('specialWord', 'sw');
```

​
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x9BSn/16/)

Comment: Yeah I see this is going to be tough to control sitewide which I suspected. I think I could probably at least apply this to h1, h2, etc which are set to be all uppercase in CSS. Satanic designer I swear, I would never design that way but I'm working off someone else's PSDs. The menus are also all caps too. If I can control just those two zones they'll have to control themselves when editing their content in the CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is (I believe) a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/x9BSn/11/

```
$.fn.changeWord = function (str, className) {
    var regStr = str + "(?=(?:[^\>]|\<[^\<]*\>)*$)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regStr, "gi");
    var txt = this.html();
    txt = txt.replace(regex, function(matched) {
            return "<span class='" + className + "'>" + str+ "</span>";
    });
    this.html(txt);
};

$('#myDiv').changeWord('specialWord', 'sw');
```

It will replace all instances of `str` (case invariant) that aren't enclosed in a tag (`< ... >`) with `str` (with the desired case).

So, if you wanted it to be "SpEcialWorD", you would accomplish that with:

```
$('#myDiv').changeWord('SpEcialWorD', 'sw');
```

as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/x9BSn/13/

You can then use some css like this to add to that content:

```
.sw:after{
    content: "TM";
    vertical-align:super;
    font-size:.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shmiddty, I forked off and I guess what I need is to modify it so it really only looks at the first letter. In this case only the first letter will ever need to be lowercase. http://jsfiddle.net/T7DNf/

Comment: @SpatialAnomaly this will work with any combination of capitalizations. It searches for whole words. I wouldn't recommend doing it per letter, personally.